# Send .PDF file generated in memory via Resposne

Tags: c#, http, itext, servicestack, httpresponse

So I have problem with Resposne file. I can send some file but it is corrupted. I know my pdf librabry works fine (checked on console app)

```
    public void Get(ClaimExportRequest exportRequest)
    {
               var str = ExportToPdf(claimDataTable);
            using (var streams = new MemoryStream(str))
            {
                base.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
                base.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", str.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                base.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                streams.WriteTo(base.Response.OutputStream);
            }
            base.Response.EndRequest(true);
    }


    public byte[] ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
    {

        var mem = new MemoryStream();
        var doc = new Document(new Rectangle(100f, 300f));
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mem);
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("This is a custom size"));
        return mem.ToArray();
    }
```

I have another part that creates CSV file and that one is fine!

```
        using (var streamOfCsvString = 

GenerateStreamFromString(csvBodyFromDt))
            {
                base.Response.UseBufferedStream = true;
                base.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=data.csv");
                base.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", streamOfCsvString.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                base.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
                streamOfCsvString.CopyTo(base.Response.OutputStream);
            }
  base.Response.EndRequest(true);
```

I tried that method too with changed data to pdf.

Any idea what is wrong in first Get? I know some lines are unnesesery but i tried everything that I found

Client

```
 downloadURL: function(url) {
    var hiddenIFrameID, iframe;
    hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader';
    iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
    if (iframe === null) {
      iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
      iframe.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    return iframe.src = url;
  }
```

**EDIT**

I made code that creates this same file at harddrive to check

```
  var doc = new Document(new Rectangle(100f, 300f));
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream("c:\\my.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {

                PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fileStream);
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("This is a custom size"));
                base.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
                base.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length",
                    fileStream.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                base.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                fileStream.CopyTo(base.Response.OutputStream); //WriteTo 
                doc.Close();
            }

            base.Response.EndRequest(true);
```

File is fine but, when doc.Close() is missing then file on the hard drive is corrupted. But on the server side now I get 0 kB files (empty files)

Comment: Have you compared the output of your working console application and your web application? In which way is the data returned by the web application broken?

Comment: I added some edit code that works locally, but still sended resposne works bad... it gives me empty files. Look at my question to the edit part

Comment: I couldn't understand your edit. doc.Close() should always be there. Is part of the iText flow. If you don't add it, file will be corrupted. You're saying that even with doc.Close() the file is not saved on disk nor outputted right on the response?

Comment: with doc.Close() file is fine on path "c:\\my.pdf" its working, but on the client side (from resposne) it is empty in case from EDIT part.. sorry for my crappy english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example code, simply adding the doc.Close() did the trick for me.

```
public byte[] ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
{

    var mem = new MemoryStream();
    var doc = new Document(new Rectangle(100f, 300f));
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mem);
    doc.Open();
    doc.Add(new Paragraph("This is a custom size"));
    doc.Close();
    return mem.ToArray();
}
```

Edit: Like I said on my comment, you should enclose the `MemoryStream` in a using, like this:

```
public byte[] ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
{
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var doc = new Document(new Rectangle(100f, 300f));
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mem);
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("This is a custom size"));
        doc.Close();
        return mem.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyways, you should at least enclose the MemoryStream in a `using` block just to ensure you free up that stream after you return the array.

Comment: I dont belive I did not try this... bounty will be added in 22 h(stack thing)

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look like this:

```
using (var dataStream = ...)
{
    ...
    dataStream.CopyTo(base.Response.OutputStream);  
}
base.Response.EndRequest(true);
```

The end of the `using` block will `Flush`, `Close` and then `Dispose` the `dataStream`. The call to `Flush` will make sure any data still sitting in a buffer will be copied over, instead of waiting for potentially more data. `EndRequest` should be called only after the data has been fully written to the `OutputStream`, so it should be called after the `using` block that will `Flush` the `dataStream`.

Comment: It is not the deal. I know I could post more, I am all using statment, i just lazy deleted my code that coints names with company names :) i am doing edit

Comment: ok, but it still not fix the problem. I added bounty from today